# how to update contents of file in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def update():
    global mylist
    i = j = 0
    mylist[:]= [] 
    key = input("enter student's tp")
    myf = open("data.txt","r+")
    ml = myf.readlines()
    #print(ml[1])
    for line in ml:
      words = line.split()
      mylist.append(words)
    print(mylist)
    l = len(mylist)
    w = len(words)
    print(w)
    print(l)
    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(w):
            print(mylist[i][j])
##            if(key == mylist[i][j]):
##                print("found at ",i,j)
##                del mylist[i][j]
##                mylist[i].insert((j+1), "xxx")
```

below is the error

> print(mylist[i][j])
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

I am trying to update contents in a file. I am saving the file in a list as lines and each line is then saved as another list of words. So "mylist" is a 2D list but it is giving me error with index

Answer (score 0):

Your `l` variable is the length of the *last* line list. Others could be shorter.

A better idiom is to use a `for` loop to iterate over a list.
But there is an even better way.

It appears you want to replace a "tp" (whatever that is) with the string `xxx` everywhere. A quicker way to do that would be to use regular expressions.

```
import re

with open('data.txt') as myf:
    myd = myf.read()
newd = re.sub(key, 'xxx', myd)
with open('newdata.txt', 'w') ad newf:
    newf.write(newd)
```